# Why my lumia 630 cant connect to certain android wifi hotspot?

Tags: lumia, wifi

I have a lumia 630 dual sim ( S.O version is 8.10.12397.895 ) and on the wifi networks list my android wifi hotspot is not listed ( I used a moto X ) so i cant connect it, but i tried to connect a wifi hotspot from a xperia z3 compact and it worked !

Comment: Can other devices connect to the moto X? did you enter the network key correctly?

Comment: I figured it out ! It was the S.O version, when i updated it worked! But it only updated after i signed in my hotmail account. 
Why the down vote?

Comment: It was not me but make a proper answer and elaborate more and I will upvote both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ! It was the O.S version. To solve this issue I had to sign in and then it was updated, since it is a phone for developement only it had no account set up.
Thank you very much!